# How to create a dynamic framework (like Carthage does) with Swift Package Manager in Xcode 11 / Swift 5.1?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

How to create a *dynamic* framework (like Carthage does)  with Swift Package Manager in Xcode 11 / Swift 5.1?

Is it at all possible or desirable, considering the default option and XCFramework?

NB: I saw a few questions about it, but now I'm asking specifically about Xcode 11 / Swift 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's that easy -
`.library(name: "...", type: .dynamic, targets: ["..."])`